Android Keystore error from GMS and NordVPN
I am having a problem on my Android TV Box X96 Max Plus Ultra (s905x4 4/64) Android 11. Tested on stock and on Slimbox ATV / AOSP with root and Magisk.
When I want to log in and connect to VPN in the NordVPN app, I get the error:

Exception during generating key keystore operation failed / exception during encryption keystore operation failed

Which would cause the login is not possible.
I did try several versions of the app. I can see the errors in the log of the app; the login procedure is:

Press Login in NordVPN
A Chrome window opens to enter the e-mail and password
After that, it returns to the app and login should be confirmed

SELinux = permissive.
I have tried around and could bypass these errors with:
Magiskpolicy deny gmscore_app keystore keystore_key gen_unique_id
chmod 660 /sys/fs/selinux/enforce
chmod 440 /sys/fs/selinux/policy #policy change not needed, just to make sure

Other things I did try: disable Google Play services (GMS) and the login and connection in NordVPN worked too (but the Google apps obviously could not work, and disabling the app is kind of equal result to denying the rule)
Only these changes would let me log in and connect without error.
Could anyone think of why this problem could exist and maybe how to fix it? And what impact (negative) on the system could these changes have?
I have uploaded logs to Pastebin.
In seconds on the timeline i did press login on .30/00 and connect on .20/50.
Logcat: https://pastebin.com/GuNcqzir
Log from Nordvpn: https://pastebin.com/t2r8jJH8
Log from begin of boot (1+2): https://pastebin.com/YVyF2k5a
https://pastebin.com/TrtKLuwE
I did find some errors in the log from boot 1 which i think could be related:
11-28 17:37:23.097     0     0 I         : [    7.136058@3]  [TEE] E/TC:? 00 tee_rpmb_verify_key_sync_counter:967 Verify key returning 0xffff000f
11-28 17:37:23.097     0     0 I         : [    7.136083@3]  [TEE] E/TC:? 00 tee_rpmb_verify_key_sync_counter:967 Verify key returning 0xffff000f
11-28 17:37:23.097     0     0 I         : [    7.136087@3]  [TEE] E/TC:? 00 tee_rpmb_init:1140 Verify key failed!
11-28 17:37:23.097     0     0 I         : [    7.136092@3]  [TEE] E/TC:? 00 tee_rpmb_init:1141 Make sure key here matches device key
[TEE] E/TC:? 00 TA panicked with code 0xffff000f

I am not sure if following errors are related to the problem:
11-28 17:37:22.473 0 0 E [ 6.511682@3] init: Unable to set property 'ro.crypto.state' from uid:0 gid:0 pid:1: Read-only property was already set
11-28 17:37:21.766 0 0 E [ 5.625557@3] selinux: SELinux: Could not set context for /mnt/vendor/odm_ext: Read-only file system
cgroup1: unknown subsys name 'schedtune' and 'blkio
11-28 17:37:21.760 0 0 E [ 2.474013@3] init: Could not set 'ro.boot.dynamic_partitions' to 'true' while loading .prop filesRead-only property was already set
11-28 17:37:21.758 0 0 E [ 1.650913@1] init: Failed to copy /avb into /metadata/gsi/dsu/avb/: No such file or directory
11-28 17:37:21.757     0     0 I [    1.609913@1]  init: [libfs_mgr]check_fs(): mount(/dev/block/by-name/metadata,/metadata,ext4)=-1: No such file or directory

11-28 17:37:25.149     0     0 I         : [    9.184167@3]  [TEE] E/TA:   fw_check_pack_version:282 The TA version (v0.2) is lower than the pkg version (v0.3).
11-28 17:37:25.149     0     0 I         : [    9.184170@3]  [TEE] E/TA:   fw_check_pack_version:283 The TA version is too low that may affect the work please update asap.
11-28 17:37:25.149     0     0 I         : [    9.184173@3]  [TEE] E/TA:   fw_check_pack_version:286 The TA ver is v0.2
11-28 17:37:25.149     0     0 I         : [    9.184176@3]  [TEE] E/TA:   fw_check_pack_version:287 The fw ver is v0.3```


Is the installed OS an official Google Android system (with pre-installed Google services and apps) or an AOSP version (even if it is provided by the device manufacturer). May be the box has no hardware backed AndroidKeystore system which is mandatory for Smartphones.

The TV Box is not certified. But it comes with pre installed Service and Apps. Not sure how to find out if its AOSP Version?
In the *.prop i can see that its sign with test-key/userdebug if thats relevant.
Under Security/Encryption there is Storage Type - Hardware-backed and Phone Encrypted.
I did find this, where a code part is for Checking for Hardware-Backed Keystore Support, but i do not know how to use this....
https://medium.com/@nachare.reena8/a-deep-dive-into-android-hardware-backed-keystore-3b0149356870
Is there an "easier" way to test or know if its supported?

Best way to trace those problems would be logcat log while the error occurs. A connected PC via adb could generate such a log or on the device itself it should be also possible to get access to logcat logs with rot permissions (e.g. via termux?). Often apps log their errors with Stacktrace to logcat. The error message and stack trace would be helpful, but finding in all those logcat messages won't be easy.

I did try logcat, but output was overwhelming. But will try again just when i try to login.
What i did was: dmesg | grep 'avc:' and there were many denials (but they actually do not matter because of selinux=0)
The thing is, only the rule to prevent Google Play Services create key_unique_id is enough (plus chmod) and the error does not happen. As i understand it should only try to set this ID at first time. But maybe can't and thats why its trying to do always. Maybe thats a trigger that if no id is set and not trying, the Hardbacked Keystore is deactivated and it only tries per Software?

It would be better if you would write everything you found out as an answer instead if squeezing it into multiple comments. May be it will be of use for other people that face a similar problem.

i will edit my question and add more infos + logs
